# How to use Dropdown list in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor-2

How to use dropdown list in cshtml?
I am using below code ,Now it looks like general HTML but problem  is not apply the bootstrap styles.

```
<div class="col-md-10">

            @{
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
     {
         Text = "AtlantaPort",
         Value = "AtlantaPort"
     });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
     {
         Text = "NewJersyTerminal",
         Value = "NewJersyTerminal",
         Selected = true
     });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
     {
         Text = "AWS",
         Value = "AWS"
     });
            }

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PortORterminal, listItems, "AtlantaPort", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", } })                        )
        </div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please clarify your intent?  Your question is open ended and vague.

Answer (score 7):

Use :

```
@Html.DropDownList("yourDropName", listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Your code edited:

```
         @{
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
  {
      Text = "AtlantaPort",
      Value = "AtlantaPort"
  });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
 {
     Text = "NewJersyTerminal",
     Value = "NewJersyTerminal",
     Selected = true
 });
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
 {
     Text = "AWS",
     Value = "AWS"
 });
        }

 @Html.DropDownList("yourDropName", listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your last line with this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PortORterminal, listItems, "AtlantaPort", new { @class = "form-control", } )
```